# How may I access my own protected API via IHttpClientFactory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to access my own API via IHttpClientFactory but am getting redirected to the login page. I had this same problem via jquery but when I included credentials: 'include' it was fixed.

This is for c# / asp.net core 2.1 MVC controller. I'm using stock identity

I've tried constructing my headers to include the Authorization with Basic and base64 encoded string including my username:password. If I allow anonymous to my endpoint then my code works fine.

The form lives in a razor page and on post sends an object in the body of the request to the endpoint. If my endpoint doesn't have the [AllowAnonymous] attribute then I get redirected back to the login and/or receive a 400 bad request

```
string contentJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Patch, baseUrl);
HttpClient client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(contentJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");
httpRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json-patch+json"));
httpRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{yourusername}:{yourpwd}")));
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);
```